# Elasticsearch 6.6 bulk insert with Postman 6.7

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

I read various guides to bulk insert data into an index.
But what ever I do the /n is not working. I guess there is some change in an Update of Postman or ES?

I try to POST to

```
 localhost:9200/urls/url/_bulk
```

In the JSON field with JSON formated

```
{ "index" : {}} \n
{ "url" : "www.url1.com" } \n
{ "index" : {}} \n
{ "url" : "www.url2.com" } \n
```

Comment: One the right side in Postman there is a "Beautify" button, but it is doing nothing.

Comment: Remove \n its a new line.

Comment: Of cause I tried this, its not working

Comment: Which response you get from ES?

Comment: Do you attach any files? I don't understand why do you have ------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW-- in the end of you request. Looks like as file attach

Answer (score 3):

Pretty weird but I got it.

The Code needs an empty line at the end:

```
"
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "_doc" } } 
{ "url" : "www.url1.com" } 
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test2", "_type" : "_doc" } } 
{ "url" : "www.url1.com" } 

"
```